# intellij IDEA multiple dex files error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, multiple-definition-error

I have IDEA 15.0.2 installed on windows 10, and have java 1.8 installed.
The android sdk API is version 19.

I have two modules in my project:

```
 project
    +---plugin-unity
    +---unity-ads
       +--- libs/unityads.jar
```

module unity-ads has a unityads.jar in libs/ folder. I make the the module unity-ads depends on unityads.jar and module plugin-unity depends on module unity-ads

When I make the project, then occurs the errors below:

> Error:Android Dex: [plugin-unity] Unable to execute DX
>   Error:Android Dex: [plugin-unity] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/unity3d/ads/android/BuildConfig;
>   Error:Android Dex: [plugin-unity] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
>   Error:Android Dex: [plugin-unity] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
>   Error:Android Dex: [plugin-unity] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
>   Error:Android Dex: [plugin-unity] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
>   Error:Android Dex: [plugin-unity] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>   Error:Android Dex: [plugin-unity] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)

What's the problem with the Intellij IDEA please? I encountered these problems many times.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:

```
The solution:
    Because the module unity-ads has the same package name 
    com.unity3d.ads.android that exists in libs/unityads.jar too.
    The IDEA will automatic produce the BuildConfig that conflicts with that in libs/unityads.jar.
    Therefore, I delete the BuildConfig from the libs/unityads.jar, and then every thing is ok.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add same class from different jar files. Try to find which class is overlapping between the jar files and remove that from the build.